# Simulate key press?

Tags: java, android, key, keypress, simulate

I am looking for a method that allows me to press freely on the Android screen. Simply put, it would emulate what a person can do to move on the Android device

I want him to press the buttons of this game. I want to make a bot.
[image]

Comment: What is the *specific programming issue* you're experiencing? Read the help file to learn [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) good questions that receive good answers and what is considered [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) for this site.

Comment: Unless you're rooted, you can't.  This functionality has been purposely removed, and every time a new way of doing it is found that way is removed as well.  If you really want to do this for personal use, the best way is to run it on an emulator and fake it from the PC side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the control of the keystrokes from a background app **you need to be root**. Instead of that, you can [use monkeyrunner to make scripts using Python](https://developer.android.com/studio/test/monkeyrunner). Another option is to use direct commands in ADB, [as stated in this answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/167001). Every option needs to be connected to a computer via USB cable.